# CMake argument passing, by value? by reference? or something else?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have 2 CMake scripts:

**Script1.cmake:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

macro(m1)
message("[DEBUG1] " ${var1})
m2(var1)  #<====================== HERE is different
endmacro(m1)


macro(m2 var2)
message("[DEBUG2] " ${var2})
set(${var2} "set from m2")
endmacro()


m1()
message("[DEBUG3] " ${var1})
```

**Script2.cmake:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

macro(m1)
message("[DEBUG1] " ${var1})
m2("var1")  #<====================== HERE is different
endmacro(m1)


macro(m2 var2)
message("[DEBUG2] " ${var2})
set(${var2} "set from m2")
endmacro()


m1()
message("[DEBUG3] " ${var1})
```

I run them with `cmake -P`. They both give the same output:

```
[DEBUG1]
[DEBUG2] var1
[DEBUG3] set from m2
```

For `[DEBUG1]`, I can explain it that because `var1` is not defined yet. So `${var1}` resolves to nothing.

But for `[DEBUG2]`, **how could it be the same to pass in `var1` and `"var1"`** ?

- For passing `"var1"`, I think the result is logically reasonable.
- But for passing `var1`, I am actually passing some non-existing variable to macro `m2`. I think there should be some error because the variable is not defined yet. But actually CMake works fine. And `${var2}` resolves to the name of `var1`.

I did some C++ programming before and I can understand pass argument **by reference** or pass argument **by value**. But it seems neither explanation fits in here. It seems there's some implicit conversion happening.

Comment: CMake is one of the strangest languages in existence. In CMake, everything is a string. `var` and `"var"` are exactly the same when passed as an argument; the quotes just let you put characters like spaces in the argument. When you expand a variable with `${var}`, that's like a lookup in a hashmap for the key which is the string `var`.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896169/justin) said, `foo(a)` and `foo("a")` are the same thing.

But you can see the difference, when passing a **list** as a parameter. When you write

```
foo(a b c d)
```

this gets turned into `foo("a;b;c;d")`. This is what happens when you call `add_executable` with a list of source files, for example. The `;` symbol is a special symbol used by CMake to separate list items. Moreover, CMake `list()` command, basically, operate on plain strings, appending or removing `;` along with items themselves.

Now, if you write

```
foo("a b c d")
```

you pass a single string with space, not a list of 4 elements.

Comment: `foo(a b c d)` isn't turned into `foo("a;b;c;d")`. If you write `foo("a;b;c;d")`, the first argument of `foo` holds the value `a;b;c;d` and `foo` was called with one argument. In short, command arguments are the special case where there is a list-like type. For variables, everything is a string, and `set(foo a b c d)` is the same as `set(foo "a;b;c;d")`